# Eslint-disable. Как убрать consistent-return и default-case?

Tags: typescript, eslint

Есть метод

```
// eslint-disable-next-line consistent-return
private assignElements(inputElement: CPInputElement): HTMLInputElement {
  // eslint-disable-next-line default-case
  switch (inputElement) {
    case 'cpMin':
      return <HTMLInputElement> this.element.querySelector('input[name="min"]');
    case 'cpMax':
      return <HTMLInputElement> this.element.querySelector('input[name="max"]');
    case 'cpStep':
      return <HTMLInputElement> this.element.querySelector('input[name="step"]');
    case 'cpFrom':
      return <HTMLInputElement> this.element.querySelector('input[name="from"]');
    case 'cpTo':
      return <HTMLInputElement> this.element.querySelector('input[name="to"]');
    case 'cpVertical':
      return <HTMLInputElement> this.element.querySelector('input[name="vertical"]');
    case 'cpRange':
      return <HTMLInputElement> this.element.querySelector('input[name="range"]');
    case 'cpScale':
      return <HTMLInputElement> this.element.querySelector('input[name="scale"]');
    case 'cpBar':
      return <HTMLInputElement> this.element.querySelector('input[name="bar"]');
    case 'cpTips':
      return <HTMLInputElement> this.element.querySelector('input[name="tip"]');
  }
}
```

```
type CPInputElement = 'cpMin'
  | 'cpMax'
  | 'cpStep'
  | 'cpFrom'
  | 'cpTo'
  | 'cpVertical'
  | 'cpRange'
  | 'cpScale'
  | 'cpBar'
  | 'cpTips';
```

который инициализирует свойства класса

```
this.cpMin = this.assignElements('cpMin');
this.cpMax = this.assignElements('cpMax');
this.cpStep = this.assignElements('cpStep');
this.cpFrom = this.assignElements('cpFrom');
this.cpTo = this.assignElements('cpTo');

this.cpVertical = this.assignElements('cpVertical');
this.cpRange = this.assignElements('cpRange');
this.cpScale = this.assignElements('cpScale');
this.cpBar = this.assignElements('cpBar');
this.cpTips = this.assignElements('cpTips');
```

и eslint правила
// eslint-disable-next-line consistent-return
убрав которое, получаю ошибку

> Expected to return a value at the end of method 'assignElements'.eslintconsistent-return

// eslint-disable-next-line default-case
которое отключает default значение для case. как убрать эти правила чтобы не было ошибок? что здесь можно вернуть в конце метода и по дефолту?

Comment: добавь определение типа `CPInputElement`

Comment: у тебя есть тип `CPInputElement` добавь в вопрос его определение.

Comment: Строковые значения, чтобы не выбрать не существующее поле. type CPInputElement = 'cpMin' | 'cpMax' | 'cpStep' | 'cpFrom' | 'cpTo' | 'cpVertical' | 'cpRange' | 'cpScale' | 'cpBar' | 'cpTips';

Comment: а чем не нравятся инлайн отключение? Ты хочешь именно отключить проверку, или исправить код, чтобы ошибка не показывалась?

Comment: инлайн? задача максимально избавиться от этих eslint-disable, правила эти должны быть включены, нужно исправить код если это возможно, всякие костыли при этом выдумывать, только для того чтобы линтер не ругался, не надо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для исправления ошибки по правилу [`default-case`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/default-case) достаточно указать ветку `default:` в `switch`, либо добавить комментарий `// no default`

Для исправления ошибки по правилу [`consistent-return`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/consistent-return) все пути прохода должны возвращать значение. Поэтому нужно либо добавить `default:` с `return`, либо добавить `return` после `switch`

Comment: Пустой return который возвращает undefined? Тогда и в инициализируемых свойствах класса будут типы CPInputElement и undefined и далее в коде появятся type assertions

Comment: @SOLID, на самом деле не важно, что ты вернешь в дефолтном return, потому что ты уже все варианты выше перебрал

Comment: @SOLID, можешь вернуть результат одного из case